# Angular7 - access parameter in Appcomponent

Tags: html, angular, typescript

My application requires a brand code to determine the style and dom.

currently the on load my URL would be www.SiteName.com/HBL (HBL = brandName)

It is a simple site where it has the only header, footer, search component.

but I need to get the Brand info from service api.

So in Appcomponent.ts, I injected ActivatedRoute and in the ngOnInit method, I subscribed paramMap.

When I load the app I am getting null parameter value.

This what I have done

**my app.compnent.html:**

```
<div class="container">
  <header [brand]="brand"></header>
  <!-- <esw-search></esw-search> -->
  <router-outlet></router-outlet> - Search will be populated thru route 
  <esw-footer></esw-footer>
</div>
```

I could have avoided router but sometimes the search page will be directly accessible.

like www.SiteName.com/HBL/search?trackingnumber=123456;language=en

**my routing component:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { NotFoundComponent } from './notfound/notfound.component';
import { SearchComponent } from './tracking-search/search/search.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: SearchComponent },
  { path: ':brandName/search', component: SearchComponent },
  { path: ':brandName/', component: SearchComponent },
  { path: '404', component: NotFoundComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '404' }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**my appcomponent.ts code:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'esw-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'logistics-tracking-ui';
  apiUrl: string;
  brand: Brand;

  constructor(
    private tracking: TrackingService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
      const brandName = params.get('brandName');
      this.tracking.getBrandData(brandName).subscribe((response) => this.brand = response);
    });
  }
  }
}
```

SearchComponent.htm:

```
<div class="card-body">

  <div class="card mx-auto">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h3 style=" text-align: center"> Track your International Package</h3>
      <div>
        <span class="ui-float-label">
          <input [(ngModel)]="trackingNumber" id="float-input" type="text" size="30" pInputText>

          <label for="float-input">Tracking Number</label>

        </span>
        <button pButton type="button" label="Click" (click)="searchTracking()"></button>
      </div>
      <esw-search-details [trackingDetails]='trackingDetails$'></esw-search-details>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

searchComponent.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'esw-search',
  templateUrl: './search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search.component.scss']
})
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {
  trackingNumber = '';
  trackingDetails$: Observable<any>;

  constructor(private trackingservice: TrackingService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  searchTracking(): void {
    alert('Search Clicked' + this.trackingNumber);
    if (!this.trackingNumber.trim()) {
      // if not search term, return empty hero array.
      // Publish error message
      console.log('Invalid Input');
      return;
    }

    this.trackingDetails$ = this.trackingservice.getTrackingDetails(this.trackingNumber, 'en-GB');


  }
```

Note: I have not added much logic to search & serachDetails component.

The issue's I have:

1. Access brand params value in App component.
2. Is this right approach to defining layout in app.coponent.html?
3. Is there any better approach I can use for this?

Sorry this is my first angular project, any help will be appriciated.

Comment: please share search component as well - SearchComponent

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to add a route for the param and that has to be added as the first in the list of routes, like

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: ':brandName/:brand', component: SearchComponent },
  { path: ':brandName/search', component: SearchComponent },
  { path: ':brandName/', component: SearchComponent },
  { path: '404', component: NotFoundComponent }, 
  { path: '', component: SearchComponent },
 { path: '**', redirectTo: '404' }
];
```

and now in the app component we can access it like:-

```
 this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
      const brandName = params['brand']
      this.tracking.getBrandData(brandName).subscribe((response) => this.brand = response);
    });
```

Comment: no this won't work. since my parameter is just value. so it's going to  '**' and 404. What I did was used route instance and got url and extracted my 3 char brand. its bit of hack but works. will update my full implementation soon.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go the route you are with passing the the exports/imports, then you have to be careful of the asynchronous loading of JS. Assuming your api call, exports, and imports are set up correctly, the Api call is completed and the brand is filled after the header component is loaded, (verify by adding console log in the app component after the api call is completed. You'll see it logs after the header loads, making it inaccessible to the header component's ngOnInit method). So you can either prevent loading until you have the required element:

```
<header *ngIf="ReturnedObject.brand" [brand]="brand"></header>
```

Or you can load the element after the page is loaded with Ng life cycle hooks, such as

```
ngAfterContentInit(){}
```

(this is not a great option as your page will load with whatever default branding, then it will reload once the brand is updated)

*my preferred method*

You can use the "{{}}" notation to dynamically name your class of an element as needed, and instead of passing an export to load another component, set the class in the parent component, then load the child component:

(in your child css)

```
.texas {
background-image: texasFlag.png;
}
 .newYork {
background-image: newYorkFlag.png;
}
```

(in your parent html)

```
<header class="{{ReturnedObject.brand}}"></header>
<your-child-component></your-child-component>
<footer class="{{ReturnedObject.brand}}"></footer>
```

That way, the class is already set by the parent before the child starts to load, taking away the "racing" your parent and child component are doing to load.